# Update thousands of rows 

Tags: c#, sql

I have this query:

```
s="update myTable set date='09/09/12' where crc32 in("+list+")";
```

But because of my list is with thousands of values I think that there is a better way to do it. I don't know which way, or how.

Update: The column `crc32` is `int`. The `list` is string like:

```
list = "2345,-6467,7865,7654,...."
```

I exeute the query by c#. the `list` contains values that I cann't get them by sql query, just through my code.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of data is stored in a list?

Comment: Think about what happens if `list = "1234); DELETE FROM myTable WHERE 1 IN (1"`

Comment: @Seph is right: use SqlCommand with [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead to avoid possibility of SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Table valued parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx Put it in a stored procedure, like:

```
create procedure mysp
@tvp tvp_list readonly
as
 update mt
 set date='09/09/12'
 from mytable mt
 join @tvp t on tvp.id = crc32
```

And call it from C# with a datatable parameter containing your crc32

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText = "prc_update",conn);

...

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("crc32",typeof(string));
..... you can add more if you like
foreach(var item in myList)
{
  var row = dt.NewRow();
  row["crc32"] = item;
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@tvp", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured);
cmd.Parameters["@tvp"].Value = dt;

.....

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I didn't understand how the store procedure help me. If you can explain me, thanks

Comment: A TVP is a list basicly. I am guessing that your list looks like, 'crc1,crc2,crc3,crc4'. It is easier to send data, in it's form (either it is int, string, etc), than to send it as a string and parse that string in the db. TO be able to use a tvp, you need to call a stored procedure with that tvp. And that procedure would look like I showed you. This is a generic implementation. In that TVP you can put whatever you want, and to have more complex conditions for your join.

Comment: Also, using a string, you are limited to the number of parameters you can send in your list. And also parsing will get slower, and so on. Using a table(tvp) all is natural for sql.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I insert my variable - list into the TVP?

Answer (score 1):

Is `List` in the database somewhere?

As an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` is probably quicker, it might even be quicker to create a table, put `List` in it, and then do the `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`.